# Python argparse option concatenation

Tags: python, argparse

Normally you can concatenate options like '-abbb', which will expand to '-a -b -b -b'. Counts would be 1 for a, abd 3 for b.

However when mixing prefix_chars I see something different ...

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( prefix_chars='-+' )
parser.add_argument( '-x', action='count', dest='counter1' )
parser.add_argument( '+x', action='count', dest='counter2' )
args = parser.parse_args( '-xxx +xxx -xxx'.split() )
print( 'counter1 = ' + str(args.counter1) )
print( 'counter2 = ' + str(args.counter2) )
```

Running this results in:

```
counter1 = 8
counter2 = 1
```

Apparently '+xxx' doesn't expand to '+x +x +x', but to '+x -x -x'.

Changing the prefix_chars to '+-' results in:

```
counter1 = 2
counter2 = 7
```

Now '-xxx' expands to '-x +x +x'.

Is this defined behaviour, or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour: I get 6 and 3 consistently, for Python 3.5.1.

Comment: 6 and 3 for python 2.7 too

Comment: I tried it interactively in Idle, results in 6 and 3 too.

Comment: Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Jul  4 2014, 14:51:17) goes wrong

Comment: What point release is that? 2.7.9? Since your result contradict those of Alan, you may want to try and upgrade your Python 2.7 version to 2.7.11.

Comment: Does argparse even officially support identically-named options that only differ by their prefix character?

Comment: What constitutes 'official support'?  Explicit mention in the documentation, or working code?  The documentation is more of a users guide than a complete specification, and as such is incomplete in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

This was patched in late 2010, in early 2.7

http://bugs.python.org/issue9352

================

I'm not aware of bug/issues or code changes that would affect this, but I could dig into it.

For a start, strings of single prefix options are handled rather deeply in the parsing.  In the current `argparse.py` the relevant code is:

```
class ArgumentParser
  def _parse_known_args
    # function to convert arg_strings into an optional action
      def consume_optional(start_index):

        match_argument = self._match_argument
        action_tuples = []
        while True:
            ...
                chars = self.prefix_chars  # e.g. the `-+` parameter
                if arg_count == 0 and option_string[1] not in chars:
                    action_tuples.append((action, [], option_string))
                    char = option_string[0]
                    option_string = char + explicit_arg[0]
                    new_explicit_arg = explicit_arg[1:] or None
                    optionals_map = self._option_string_actions
                    if option_string in optionals_map:
                        action = optionals_map[option_string]
                        explicit_arg = new_explicit_arg
                    else:
                        msg = _('ignored explicit argument %r')
                        raise ArgumentError(action, msg % explicit_arg)
```

It's the pair of lines:

```
 char = option_string[0]
 option_string = char + explicit_arg[0]
```

that preserves the initial `-/+` when handling the repeated characters (in the unparsed `explicit_arg` string.

I can imagine the case where the code split `+xyz` into `+x`,`-y`,`-z`, and was corrected to use `+x`,`+y`,`+z`.  But it will require some digging into bug/issues and/or the Python repository to find out if and when that change was made.

What does your problem `argparse.py` have at this point?